# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 when compiling c++

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a small C++ program that I modified from another classmate (which was permitted for the assignment), but I cannot get the code to compile.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::cout;

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int bufferSize = 100;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto edit = string(argv[1]);
    auto source = string(argv[2]);

    std::ifstream input(source);
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    input.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, bufferSize);
    vector<string> remove;

    string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        string item;

        while (std::getline(ss, item, ',')) {
            remove.push_back(item);
        }
    }

    map<string, string> findReplace;
    for (auto value : remove) {
        findReplace.insert(std::pair<string, string>(value, ""));
    }

    vector<string> fileContent;

    std::ifstream input2(edit);
    char buffer2[bufferSize];
    input2.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer2, bufferSize);

    string line2;
    while(std::getline(input2, line2)) {
        fileContent.push_back(line2);
    }

    for (auto pair : findReplace) {
        std::for_each(fileContent.begin(), fileContent.end(), [&pair] (string &substrate) {
            std::size_t startPos = 0;
            std::size_t matchPos;
            string first = pair.first;
            string second = pair.second;
            while ((matchPos = substrate.find(first, startPos)) != string::npos) {
                substrate.replace(matchPos, first.length(), second);
                startPos = matchPos + first.length();
            }
        });
    }

    std::ofstream output(edit);
    for (auto portion : fileContent) {
        output << portion << std::endl;
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Time elapsed: "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
    << "ms";
}
```

Every time I compile (OS X 10.10) using...

```
gcc -std=c++11 delete.cpp
```

I receive

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Still searching here and google, but if anyone can see a reason for this, I would be greatly indebted to you. (This is my first C++ program).

Answer (score 3):

When compiling C++ programs, you need to use `g++`* (instead of `gcc`) so that the program gets linked with the proper libraries.

<sub>Note that you might still use `gcc` but then you'd have to link the required libraries yourself manually.</sub>

Comment: D'oh! If I used `gcc`, it correctly allowed the `lambda function` in the last few lines. I'm using `g++ -Wc++11-extensions delete.cpp` and it errors out saying its expecting an expression in the last `std::for_each` call.

Comment: It compiles fine for me when using both `clang++ -std=c++11 delete.cc` and `g++ -std=c++11 delete.cc` (clang 3.5, g++ 4.9.1).

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling c++ program using command for c. Use g++ instead of gcc.